# How I create a view with the record count of different tables

Tags: mysql, create-view

I need to create a **view** with the record count from 3 different tables but with the same columns.

That is, these queries

```sql
SELECT COUNT (*) AS count_a from table1 ta
SELECT COUNT (*) AS count_b from table2 tb
SELECT COUNT (*) AS count_c from table3 tc
```

Introduced in a view, the `join` can be a solution but I think this would take a lot of work, and likewise being a different count in each table, when using join it would discard some, if in a table there are 100, 200, 15. No I know if the join would be the solution to this.

I wanted to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` but reviewing a bit does not seem to be a solution, anyway. In simple words I want the count of different tables in a view so that it is displayed

Desired result

| count_a | count_b | count_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 15 |

Greetings and thanks in advance

PS: right now I do not remember well how the JOIN works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display only the result of these 3 counts, without any join between tables. I suggest to use a script like this :

```
create view desired_result
as select * from (
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_a from table1) t1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_b from table2) t2,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_c from table3) t3);
```

You can try it with this [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1037a401ccb88f881cbe50c1e7263571)

Comment: The parenthesis after the `from` is too much, it marks a syntax error, but it works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try a query like this:

```
SELECT
(SELECT count(*) FROM table1) AS count_a,
(SELECT count(*) FROM table2) AS count_b,
(SELECT count(*) FROM table3) AS count_c;
```

Comment: sorry - my mistake , copy paste. i change it

Comment: How easy you make it, hahaha thank you I did not know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you like without `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
(SELECT count(*) as count_a FROM table1) AS count_a,
(SELECT count(*) as count_b FROM table2) AS count_b,
(SELECT count(*) as count_c FROM table3) AS count_c;
```

If you like with `JOIN`:

```
SELECT ta.count_a, tb.count_b, tc.count_c FROM
 (
SELECT COUNT (*) AS count_a, 1 AS rn from table1) ta
JOIN (
SELECT COUNT (*) AS count_b, 1 AS rn from table2) tb
ON ta.rn = tb.rn
 JOIN (
SELECT COUNT (*) AS count_c, 1 AS rn from table3)  tc
ON ta.rn = tc.rn
```